# Microsoft Outlook 2010 Script won't run after application is closed

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2010

I am create an Outlook 2010 rule that runs a script to forward an email, while at the same time removing the original email header information.

The point of this script was to make it seem like the email is being sent from my account but it's actually being forwarded from another account.

The script/rule worked when originally implemented but after I closed out of the application the rule doesn't seem to work.

Is there a reason why closing Outlook 2010 would cause a rule to not to run or could there be another cause? Has anyone else had this issue.

The script I created is below:

```
Sub SendNew(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objMsg As MailItem
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

objMsg.Body = Item.Body
objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject
objMsg.Recipients.Add "email@email.com"
objMsg.Recipients.Add "email@email.com"

objMsg.Send

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Client side rules obviously run only when the client (Outlook) is open. Server side rules (Exchange only) always run, but they do not run any scripts and are limited to things like forwarding.

Comment: Right. I re-opened Outlook but the rule wouldn't run. Does it stop altogether when the Client closes at any time. I would think it would turn back on once Outlook opens up again.

Comment: Was that a new mail rule on an Exchange mailbox? When you launch Outlook, the mail has already arrived, so the vent will nto be raised.

Comment: I'm actually sending the email myself to test the rule so Outlook is open and running when I'm sending the email. So far, the only time the rule triggered was when I originally created it. Ever since then it has not triggered.

Comment: Are you saying your rules becomes disabled after you restart Outlook?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is disabled but the rule hasn't even worked since the first time I created it. Since then I've restarted outlook a few times.